# How raft algorithm maintains strong read consistency in case of write failure followed by a node failure

Tags: consensus, raft

Consider three nodes(A,B,C)  getting key/value data. And the following steps happened

1. Node A receive key:value (1:15). It is a leader
2. It replicate to node B and node C
3. Entry made to node B in pre commit log
4. Node C fail the entry
5. Ack from node B is lost.
6. Nod A fail the entry and sent failure to client
7. Node A is still leader and B is not in quorum
8. Client read from node A for key 1 and it returned old value.
9. node A is down
10. Node B and node C is up
11. now node B has an entry in precommit log and node C doesn't.

How does log matching happen at this time. Is node Bgoing to commit that entry or going to discard it. If it is going to commit thenit would be read inconsistent or if it is going to discard then there could be data loss in other cases

Answer (score 7):

The error is in step 8. Every read operation must be replicated to other nodes otherwise you risk getting stale data, the system should serve read after it writes a dummy value to the log. In your case (`B` is offline), the "read" must affect nodes `A` and `C`, so when node `B` comes back online and `A` dies, `C` would be able to invalidate `B`'s records.

This is a tricky problem and even Etcd run into it in the past (now it's [fixed](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/issues/741)).

Comment: It makes sense writing a dummy entry and replicating it for read. But it can impact the performance of reads. But i guess that is a penalty to do consistent reads.

Comment: @rishabhmittal: Yes, this makes reads linearizable which has a cost. See also the PACELC theorem. Note that there are Paxos variants that employ the use of read leases to grant the ability for nodes to do linearizable reads entirely locally.

Comment: @GManNickG Can you please name those Paxos variants? As I understand it's impossible to achieve it with leases because any system (except hard real-time systems) may experience uncontrollable freezes at any time (GC pauses, virtualization issues etc.) so the leases may expire without a system knowing about it.

Comment: See "Paxos Quorum Leases: Fast Reads Without Sacrificing Writes", which is essentially a more structured approach to ensuring leases are properly respect. Indeed, one of their assumptions is that while clocks don't need to be synchronized, they do need to have similar-enough drift rate that a simple wait buffer guarantees lease expiration will be detected on the remote node. [1/2]

Comment: We're probably both on the same page of that feeling uncomfortable in practice. However, I think in many circumstances it is an acceptable assumption that the software can further safe-guard (e.g., if the clock ever goes back in time or doesn't advance after <process I know takes non-zero time>, crash). I think it falls under the same category of issues as cosmic ray bit-flips - practical hardware considerations that you can assign an SLA to and plan for (though to be fair, clock drift violations are going to be way more common). [2/2]

Comment: Oh, I'm not talking about the clock rate issues (worrying about them indeed like worrying about cosmic ray), I'm talking about uncontrollable freezes caused by GC or VM migration. The latter seems to be a way more frequent event which has similar consequences: a freeze may happen after a system checks that it still has the lease but before it serves a request.

Comment: I was being lazy and packing those into clock rate issues. :) That is, like using ECC to mitigate some bit errors you would only run these on bare metal with runtimes without GC (for example). I guess essentially agreeing with your first point that you need a hard-real time system, or one close enough to your error tolerance.

Comment: By before it serves a request, do you mean before sending the response but after reading and validating the lease? That would still be linearizable right? Otherwise, I think as long as you verify your lease after your local read you're okay - if you paused between, as long as your hardware clock still went up you'll detect your read became out of date. If you're using a software clock that pauses with the VM, I think you're screwed, but I pack that back in with "get a clock that ticks at a ~constant rate".

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry for the misinformation. The linearizability won't be affected by the freezes because it's fine to return stale data as long as they were valid at some point of the request execution.